# jdbc odbc driver

Tags: ms-access, jdbc, odbc

When i go to data sources in control panel and click on ms access driver. I get an error.. i.e.

**setup routines for ms access driver odbc driver** cannot be found? Wha'ts wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try re registering ODBCCONF.DLL by running the command “regsvr32 odbcconf.dll”. We had this on one computer once and it fixed it so might work for you